# I Got error message of using a bool method in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I wanna get a bool to show if person are in company or not and have the code bellow but I get this error : Method System.String GetPresent_Status(Int32) has no supported translation to SQL.

```
 internal bool GetPresent_Status(int employeeID)
    {
        using (LinqDataContext context = DataContext)
        {
            var dateString = Common.Date.GregorianToPersian(DateTime.Now.Date, Common.Date.DateStringType.Short);
            var result = context.vwDailyWorks
                .Where(ss => ss.EmployeeID == employeeID && ss.Date ==dateString)
                .Select(t => t.Even_Odd).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Convert.ToInt16(result) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
```

and I use this code here:
Note that if if use True Or False directly near the Status , it work!!

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeInfo> GetAllVisibleEmployeesInfo(string sortBy, string name, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string Department, bool onlyPresence = false)
    {
        name = Common.Converter.ConvertToFarsiYK(name ?? "").Trim();
        var GetNowString = Common.Date.GregorianToPersian(DateTime.Now.Date, Common.Date.DateStringType.Short);
        
        using (LinqDataContext context = DataContext)
        {
            if (Department == null)
            {
                Department = "";
            }

            List<EmployeeInfo> result = context.vwDailyWorks
                .Where(q => (q.Visible == true))
                .Where(q => (q.DepartmentName.Contains(Department)))
                .Where(q => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ||
                                (q.FirstName.Contains(name) ||
                                q.LastName.Contains(name) ||
                                q.Position.Contains(name) ||
                                q.Floor.Contains(name) ||
                                (q.Ext_Tel ?? -1).ToString().Contains(name) ||
                                q.Email.Contains(name) ||
                                q.DepartmentName.Contains(name)))
                        )

                .GroupBy(t => t.EmployeeID)
                .Select(t => new EmployeeInfo
                {
                    FirstName = t.Max(s => s.FirstName),
                    LastName = t.Max(s => s.LastName),
                    Position = t.Max(s => s.Position),
                    DepartmentName = t.Max(s => s.DepartmentName),
                    Unit = t.Max(s => s.Unit),
                    Floor = t.Max(s => s.Floor),
                    Status =GetPresent_Status(t.Key),
                    Extension = t.Max(s => s.Ext_Tel),
                    Info = GetPresenceInfo(t.Key, false),
                    ID = t.Key,
                    Email = t.Max(s => s.Email),
                    StatusInfo = GetStatusInfo(t.Key, false)
                }
                        )
                .Where(w =>  w.Status == true)
                .OrderBy(sortBy)
                .Skip(startRowIndex)
                .Take(maximumRows)
                .ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Call `ToList()` after the GtoupBy. E.g `.GroupBy(t => t.EmployeeID).ToList()` so you can call your method `GetPresent_Status` in memory. The downside of this, is you are pulling back all the data, before you filter. The other approach is to not use that method there, and in turn use it after you have materialized the data

Comment: it work by doing this ;
`Status = Convert.ToBoolean(context.vwDailyWorks.Where(ss => ss.EmployeeID == t.Key && ss.Date == GetNowString).SingleOrDefault()),`
but some other weird  errors comes